# Excessive tabs in an inline codeblock cause repeated sideways scrolling of chat window for other users

Tags: bug, chat, firefox, code-block

This affects at least Firefox. When a message has an inline codeblock containing a long string of tabs this causes the chat window to have a horizontal scrollbar and to scroll spontaneously left and right as new messages appear.

This does not happen when messages use fixed font to create code blocks.

---

Since the chat sandbox was difficult to test in due to already having the problem, I've tested this in [a new room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57549/tabs-sandbox) and confirmed that the problem does not happen when pasting in a long string of tabs after 4 spaces (to create a code block). It only happens when enclosing a long string of tabs in backticks to create `inline code`.

Comment: For reference, the name was `0<28 tabs>'`. Also, it made the user's name unpingable (though replies worked). I'm fairly certain this was chat removing repeated whitespace thouhg.

Comment: Personally, if tabs are to be allowed in usernames, I think they should be handled as spaces are: autocompletion of a username with tabs should strip the tabs.

Comment: Furthermore this problem *does* affect the chat transcript as well

Comment: Chat transcript for reference: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36882823#36882823

Comment: This is [tag:status-norepro].

Comment: A bug report for the discrepancy between the tab completion of the username and the pingable username has been posted https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295060/discrepancy-between-tab-completion-of-username-and-pingable-version-of-username