# Tab auto-completion of username won't ping in chat if username contains tabs

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, display-names

When there are tabs in a username then when you tab complete the username the tabs are included but to ping the username you must omit the tabs.

Note that the reply feature (beginning a message with `:<msg number>`) still functions normally.

### Steps to reproduce

My chat username is

```
0                                                                                                               '
```

*(Note that while my username contains 28 tabs, one tab is sufficient to cause the problem)*

Enter a chatroom such as the [sandbox](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1/sandbox) and type `@0` into chat. A suggestion will appear for a username that appears to be `@0 '`. Hit tab. The full username will appear in your chatbox (including the 28 tabs). Send the chat message. I will not be pinged and when hovering over the chat message the username will not be highlighted. Type `@0'` into a chat message and send it. The username will be properly highlighted and I will be pinged.

#### Reference

- https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36884064#36884064

Comment: [tag:status-do-not-abuse-names]. (I mean, people can also have a fancy unicode name which is actually empty and won't be pingable as well. If you want to be pingable, just have a normal name.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard This username only has 7-bit ASCII chars (`0`, 28×`\t`, `'`). Tabs are normally considered whitespace, since they get reduced to a single space (`\s`). In pings, chars that are considered whitespace are supposed to be removed. Unfortunately, here they must be manually removed, while they should be automatically removed (the user is still pingable).

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος I never said this is not a bug. Just that it's a bug not worth fixing, as the actual solution is "just don't do that"

Comment: @ShadowWizard I think the actual fix is to entirely ban tabs from usernames as "special characters".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks, this has been fixed in chat